# Type error when ionic serving with FilePicker-Phonegap-iOS-Plugin in ionic 3

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic3, filepicker

i'm developping an Ionic3 App and wants to allow user to upload files from their devices. I’ve got an issue with cordova/phonegap file picker plugin. 
I followed the instructions here :

https://github.com/jcesarmobile/FilePicker-Phonegap-iOS-Plugin

But even using the simplest code which is given in Ionic documentation doesn't work :

```
import { IOSFilePicker } from '@ionic-native/file-picker/ngx';

constructor(private filePicker: IOSFilePicker) { }

this.filePicker.pickFile()
  .then(uri => console.log(uri))
  .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
```

I keep on getting this error :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at IOSFilePicker.pickFile (index.js:27)
```

The plugin has been correctly installed in app.module.ts with the correct ngx path.

Here some additional info about versions :

- ionic framework : 3.9.2
- Ionic App Scripts: 3.1.8
- Angular Core: 6.0.3
- Angular Compiler CLI: 6.0.3
- Node: 8.11.3
- @ionic-native/file-picker: 5.4.0
- rxjs: 6.3.3
- typescript: 2.7.2

any idea ?

Thx

Comment: you are getting error because you have imported ionic 4 component and you are using ionic 3.

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install plugin :

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-filepicker

npm install --save @ionic-native/file-picker@4
```

Add in in your app module

```
import { IOSFilePicker } from '@ionic-native/file-picker';


@NgModule({
..
   providers:[
      IOSFilePicker
   ]
})
```

Now use in your page component

```
import { IOSFilePicker } from '@ionic-native/file-picker';
```

class ...
    constructor(private filePicker: IOSFilePicker) { }

```
getFile(){

    this.filePicker.pickFile()
      .then(uri => console.log(uri))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));

}
```

Ref. https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/ios-file-picker/

Comment: Downgrade of the plugin to version 4 and removing ngx from the path corrected my problem. Thx

Comment: if you are creating new project, better use ionic 4